# Different serial ports get the same COM identifier in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, usb, serial-port

We're using Windows 10 for testing several different devices, connected to several USB hubs. Some of these have the same VID/PID, some different. There are a lot of devices being plugged in and out, and we see that suddenly we get major problems when enumerating the serial ports (USB CDC ACM ports to be exact):

[image]

ALL the serial ports get the same COM-number! How is that even possible? Of course, when we are trying to talk to most of them at the same time, this makes it impossible. How can this happen from time to time, sometimes after reboot, sometimes not?

We've also seen instabilities when the COM-number starts growing over 250, so we built a tool clearing out all registry entries. This seems to work for some time, but again, not all the time. Reinstalling the whole OS works in the beginning, but quickly starts giving us problems again. Plugging in the same devices on a Linux machine always gives us a new /dev/ttyACMx. We've also seen this problematic behavior in Windows 7.

Comment: This is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1587613/windows-10-two-serial-usb-devices-were-given-an-identical-port-number) question and likely has to do either with drivers, USB serial firmware, or the hubs. If the USB serial cables are plugged directly into the PC's USB ports, is the issue still present? If no, it's the hubs, and if yes, it's a poor implentation by the serial cable's firmware and/or Windows drivers.

Comment: Thank you. Wow, it's even the same COM port. But that question is just two devices. I don't want to believe that all of these devices gets the same COM from race conditions. Also, it being from several manufacturers causes me to believe that it's not the devices fault at all. Windows drivers more likely.

Comment: USB Serial cable firmware _(e.g. the firmware in the chip on the USB head of the cable)_ is not the same quality across the board. FTDI is the gold standard, but it's not uncommon for non-FTDI serial firmware to operate in a non-expected way due to poor implementation by that manufacturer _(i.e. that specific issue has nothing to do with Windows as an OS and everything to do with the USB serial cable manufacturer's implementation of the serial firmware and serial drivers)_. Typically, USB serial cables require the installation of the serial drivers provided by the cable's manufacturer.

Comment: _Cont'd..._ Any PC with BT will likely have ~4 `COM` ports occupied for serial over BT, which is why it's likely starting at `COM4` - in Device Manager, expand the _Ports_ list. Also, why are the serial cables registering as mount points `G:`, `F:`, `H:`, `I:`, and `E:`?

Comment: These are not FTDI controllers, but SEGGER debuggers and other devices. They are using USB CDC ACM, and the reason for them registering mount points is that they are both mass storage devices, and exposes three USB CDC ACM ports each. The drivers are installed and working most of the time, as I said, but some times this happens.

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to the manufacturer of the USB serial cables, as this is either an issue with the cable's firmware/driver implementation in Windows or an issue with the hub(s); either way, it's an issue the manufacturer of the cable should be able to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: When it is four different vendors (five including USB hub), then I think this is a Windows issue. Will reach out to the manufacturers as well

Comment: As I mentioned previously in my first comment, to figure out which component is the issue, disconnect all from the hub and directly plug them into the USB ports on the motherboard to determine whether it's the cable(s) or the hub. This isn't an OS issue, as Windows only interprets what the firmware of the hub/cables, are providing (e.g. if it's found the cables are the issue, then it's a driver issue, which is the responsibility of the manufacturer, not Microsoft, as it is not within Microsoft's purview to develop hardware drivers/firmware for devices they don't manufacture).